# Switch from Android Studio to Netbeans

Tags: java, android, netbeans, gradle

Hello i want to import my android studio project to Netbeas but i get this error with gradle.

> org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip'.
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:57)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
>       at org.netbeans.gradle.model.GenericModelFetcher.getModels(GenericModelFetcher.java:166)
>       at org.netbeans.gradle.project.model.NbGradle18ModelLoader$ProjectModelFetcher.getModels(NbGradle18ModelLoader.java:361)
>       at org.netbeans.gradle.project.model.NbGradle18ModelLoader.loadModels(NbGradle18ModelLoader.java:66)
>       at org.netbeans.gradle.project.model.GradleModelLoader.loadModelWithProgress(GradleModelLoader.java:514)
>       at org.netbeans.gradle.project.model.GradleModelLoader.access$700(GradleModelLoader.java:70)
>       at org.netbeans.gradle.project.model.GradleModelLoader$6.run(GradleModelLoader.java:344)
>       at org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.GradleDaemonManager.runNonBlockingGradleTask(GradleDaemonManager.java:36)
>       at org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.GradleDaemonManager.access$100(GradleDaemonManager.java:23)
>       at org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.GradleDaemonManager$2.execute(GradleDaemonManager.java:126)
>       at org.jtrim.concurrent.AbstractTaskExecutorService$FunctionWrapper.execute(AbstractTaskExecutorService.java:270)
>       at org.jtrim.concurrent.AbstractTaskExecutorService$TaskOfAbstractExecutor.execute(AbstractTaskExecutorService.java:340)
>       at org.jtrim.concurrent.Tasks$RunOnceCancelableTask.execute(Tasks.java:342)
>       at org.jtrim.concurrent.SingleThreadedExecutor$QueuedItem.runTask(SingleThreadedExecutor.java:919)
>       at org.jtrim.concurrent.SingleThreadedExecutor$QueuedItem.access$1200(SingleThreadedExecutor.java:898)
>       at org.jtrim.concurrent.SingleThreadedExecutor$Impl$Worker.executeTask(SingleThreadedExecutor.java:815)
>       at org.jtrim.concurrent.SingleThreadedExecutor$Impl$Worker.processQueue(SingleThreadedExecutor.java:827)
>       at org.jtrim.concurrent.SingleThreadedExecutor$Impl$Worker.run(SingleThreadedExecutor.java:861)
>       at org.jtrim.concurrent.SingleThreadedExecutor$Impl$1.run(SingleThreadedExecutor.java:453)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Build file 'C:\Users\Mike\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Snorechattt\app\build.gradle' line: 17
>   A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
>       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:77)
>       at org.gradle.initialization.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:47)
>       at org.gradle.initialization.StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.transform(StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.java:30)
>       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:108)
>       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.getBuildAnalysis(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:97)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.configure(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:45)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:49)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>       at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:71)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
>   Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
>       at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:76)
>       at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$1.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:148)
>       at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:156)
>       at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:39)
>       at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
>       at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
>       at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:55)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:487)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:85)
>       at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:47)
>       at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
>       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:129)
>       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
>       ... 34 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler.getAndCheckSdkFolder(SdkHandler.java:102)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler$getAndCheckSdkFolder.call(Unknown Source)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.BaseExtension.getDefaultProguardFile(BaseExtension.groovy:622)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject$GroovyObjectAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:275)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:127)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.ConfigureDelegate.invokeMethod(ConfigureDelegate.java:78)
>       at build_czqcjwedq9w046ft6xpjial51$_run_closure1_closure4_closure5.doCall(C:\Users\Mike\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Snorechattt\app\build.gradle:17)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:67)
>       at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:130)
>       at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:91)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection$ContainerElementsDynamicObject.invokeMethod(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:341)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:150)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:150)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.ConfigureDelegate.invokeMethod(ConfigureDelegate.java:62)
>       at build_czqcjwedq9w046ft6xpjial51$_run_closure1_closure4.doCall(C:\Users\Mike\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Snorechattt\app\build.gradle:15)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:67)
>       at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:130)
>       at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:91)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractNamedDomainObjectContainer.configure(AbstractNamedDomainObjectContainer.java:68)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractNamedDomainObjectContainer.configure(AbstractNamedDomainObjectContainer.java:24)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:59)
>       at org.gradle.api.Action$execute.call(Unknown Source)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.BaseExtension.buildTypes(BaseExtension.groovy:327)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension_Decorated.buildTypes(Unknown Source)
>       at build_czqcjwedq9w046ft6xpjial51$_run_closure1.doCall(C:\Users\Mike\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Snorechattt\app\build.gradle:14)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:67)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ExtensionsStorage$ExtensionHolder.configure(ExtensionsStorage.java:145)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ExtensionsStorage.configureExtension(ExtensionsStorage.java:69)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultConvention$ExtensionsDynamicObject.invokeMethod(DefaultConvention.java:207)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:150)
>       at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.methodMissing(BasicScript.java:79)
>       at build_czqcjwedq9w046ft6xpjial51.run(C:\Users\Mike\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Snorechattt\app\build.gradle:3)
>       at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:74)
>       ... 46 more

Comment: why are you switching to Netbeans ?

Comment: Because i want to use Glassfish or tomcat and android studio dosen't support them

Answer (score 0):

There is a cause in stacktrace: `SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable`